# How to distribute a list of rectangles of varying width and height, maximizing distance between items, inside a rectangular container?

Tags: algorithm, game-physics, bin-packing

I need a function that takes in two inputs:

- a bounding box with a width and height
- an array of rectangular items with varying width and height (all smaller than the bounding box)

It would output an array of the same items with an additional `position` property (can mutate the original items), with `x` and `y` such that distances between items are maximized (note - not distance between the points, need to take into consideration of the dimensions of the item).

It doesn't have to be the mathematically proven best solution, a good-enough heuristic is okay

I've looked at bin-packing, but it seems to do the opposite of what I want.

Any language is acceptable, even pseudocode.

I'm not sure where even to start. Right now I'm just randomizing positions and occasionally end up with overlapping items, which is undesirable.

Comment: more context please. what language?

Comment: Not really important, could be pseudocode. Currently need it in javascript but don't want to limit to js only solutions

Comment: When is it good enough? Is it good enough if you generate a bunch of random potential placements and take the one that maximizes the distance to already placed items?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head that there is a way to derive an optimal solution, but one suggestion would be to model something like attaching a compressed spring to each pair of centroids and iterating the model until equilibrium (or near enough)...

Comment: @harold that's a good question. Ideally it would be something that doesn't require iteration, but I suspect that might not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only need a heuristic, and not an optimal solution (which nobody can give you ATM, as "distances between items are maximized" is a vague term):

Though bin-packing seems to be the "opposite", it can be used. Take a smaller (smallest) box that they fit into, and do the packing, then stretch it along with the calculated positions.

Comment: interesting solution. the follow-up question would be, how to find the smallest box they all fit into... Also, your version could work only for one direction, when the stetching in x-direction is much larger or smaller than in y-direction

Comment: variation of your solution: take the smallest box that they fit into AND that is proportional to the given bounding box.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. as for how: mm... binary search?

Comment: wouldn't know how, but I'm not that much into algorithms. Probably I'd start with a very small box, sort biggest to smallest item and insert them one after the other. Whenever an item fits, I simply put it in as close to the others as possible. When an item does not fit, I increase the bounding box until it fits. Would be nice to know, whether or not the items are rectangular...

Comment: Thansk for the answer discussion. The items can be assumed to be rectangular (I'll add that to the question)